# Finding the largest power of a number that divides a factorial in haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

So I am writing a haskell program to calculate the largest power of a number that divides a factorial.

```
largestPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Here `largestPower a b` has find largest power of `b` that divides `a!`.

Now I understand the math behind it, the way to find the answer is to repeatedly divide `a` (just a) by `b`, ignore the remainder and finally add all the quotients. So if we have something like

```
largestPower 10 2
```

we should get 8 because 10/2=5/2=2/2=1 and we add 5+2+1=8

However, I am unable to figure out how to implement this as a function, do I use arrays or just a simple recursive function.

I am gravitating towards it being just a normal function, though I guess it can be done by storing quotients in an array and adding them.

Comment: Yes, a simple recursive function should do. Though you can also use a list if you want.

Comment: @Bergi could you give me hint or something for the function, i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: If I read it right, no recursion necessary a simple loop should suffice: (pseudocode): dividend = a; power=0; while (dividend >= b) { dividend=round(dividend/b);power+=1;}

Comment: @John There are no loops in Haskell.

Comment: Recursion is the idiomatic way to implement this. Try writing out your mathematical understanding more formally.

Comment: Thanks Bergi - then recurse using the same protocol, should suffice

Comment: If you know `largestPower (a/b) b`, how do you find `largestPower a b` given that information? What is your base case? Let me know if you want me to write out a full solution for you.

Comment: You do not have to **add** `5+2+1`. You simply count that there are three divisions, and then you calculate `2^3 = 8`. The fact that this sum works is just a co-incidence.

Comment: @John the problem i am having is that i understand the math and basic algorithm but am having problems writing the recursive function. Do i write something like say devideSum x y =  x/y + devideSum x/y y  ?

Comment: WillemVanOnsem that also works but i do not know how to implement that also @Lazersmoke you'r write i am having problems finding the base case

Comment: @sgman You're defintion is correct except that `div a b` is the integer division function in Haskell. Your base case is `a < b`

Comment: @Lazersmoke so the base case will be if a<b = 1 ? or should it be something else ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are incorrect. 5+2+1 is the right calculation to do: `10/2=5` factors in `[1..10]` are even, hence contribute `2^5` to the product; an additional `5/2=2` factors are even after taking out the factor contributed earlier, hence contribute an additional `2^2` to the product; and an additional `2/2=1` factors are even after taking out the factors contributed earlier, hence contribute an additional `2^1` to the product. Thus the whole product is a multiple of `2^5*2^2*2^1 = 2^{5+2+1}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem (Though I suspect this argument breaks down for composite factors. I don't see a cleverer algorithm than doing this for each prime factor, then doing some divisions by their multiplicities and taking the max of the results, but I would be shocked if my imagination had covered all the bases here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Recursion without an *accumulator*

You can simply write a recursive algorithm and sum up the result of each call. Here we have two cases:

- `a` is less than `b`, in which case the largest power is `0`. So:

  ```
  largestPower a b | a < b = 0
  ```
- `a` is greater than or equal to `b`, in that case we divide `a` by `b`, calculate `largestPower` for that division, and add the division to the result. Like:

  ```
                   | otherwise = d + largestPower d b
                   where d = (div a b)
  ```

Or putting it together:

```
largestPower a b | a < b = 1
                 | otherwise = d + largestPower d b
                 where d = (div a b)
```

## Recursion with an *accumuator*

You can also use *recursion* with an *accumulator*: a variable you pass through the recursion, and update accordingly. At the end, you return that accumulator (or a function called on that accumulator).

Here the accumulator would of course be the *running product* of divisions, so:

```
largestPower = largestPower' 0
```

So we will define a function `largestPower'` (mind the accent) with an accumulator as first argument that is initialized as `1`.

Now in the recursion, there are two cases:

- `a` is less than `b`, we simply return the accumulator:

  ```
  largestPower' r a b | a < b = r
  ```
- otherwise we multiply our accumulator with `b`, and pass the division to the `largestPower'` with a recursive call:

  ```
                      | otherwise = largestPower' (d+r) d b
                      where d = (div a b)
  ```

Or the full version:

```
largestPower = largestPower' 1

largestPower' r a b | a < b = r
                    | otherwise = largestPower' (d+r) d b
                    where d = (div a b)
```

## Naive correct algorithm

The algorithm is not correct. A "naive" algorithm would be to simply divide every item and keep decrementing until you reach `1`, like:

```
largestPower 1 _ = 0
largestPower a b = sumPower a + largestPower (a-1) b
    where sumPower n | n `mod` b == 0 = 1 + sumPower (div n b)
                     | otherwise = 0
```

So this means that for the `largestPower 4 2`, this can be written as:

```
largestPower 4 2 = sumPower 4 + sumPower 3 + sumPower 2
```

and:

```
sumPower 4 = 1 + sumPower 2
           = 1 + 1 + sumPower 1
           = 1 + 1 + 0
           = 2

sumPower 3 = 0

sumPower 2 = 1 + sumPower 1
           = 1 + 0
           = 1
```

So `3`.

Comment: Is the algorithm here correct? I think it should be `(div a b) + largestPower (div a b) b`

Comment: @Lazersmoke: Say you calculate `largestPower 2 3`. This is supposed to be `1`, not `2`... The addition as is specified in the question is simply an incorrect algorithm.

Comment: @Lazersmoke: see note added to the answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i tried this code, and it gives the wrong answer in case of largestPower 10 5, it should be 2 but it gives 5 as the answer

Comment: @sgman: somehow I skipped the factorial part. Will update the answer.

Comment: i figured your mistake @WillemVanOnsem its actually a<b =0 and then you have otherwise = (div a b) + (largestPower (div a b) b)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im not sure if links are allowed in this site but if they are i can link you the page that explains the math of the algo

Comment: @sgman: but `0` is **not** a power of `b` (regardless what that `b` is)...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am not using the power logic, i am using that quotient some thing, i actually just did it by kinda trial and error cause i figured since im calculating sum (by my logic) then adding a 1 can mess stuff up so i just changed it to a 0.

Comment: @sgman: but have you any proof that your "algorithm" is correct. I was under the impression that you knew *how* to calculate it, but not how to *implement* it in Haskell. Now it seems to turn out, that you do not know whether the algoritm is correct itself?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i initially knew that it was correct cause i had googled it a bit but then you said it was wrong so i changed my mind, anyway i got it now, its all good thanks.

Comment: I downvoted. This appears to be answering a substantially different question than the one asked.

Comment: No, 4 is the correct answer for `largestPower 10 3`, because 3^4 is the largest power of 3 that divides 10! evenly. I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but it doesn't seem to be the one asked for. I'm not claiming to have a proof that the proposed algorithm is correct, but your counterexample is wrong.

Comment: @amalloy: funny though that there was a concurrent edit. :) Carl Jung would have called that *synchronicity* :) (although it is more that some people have a job, and thus cannot make edits every moment of the day).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm as stated can be implemented quite simply:

```
largestPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
largestPower 0 b = 0
largestPower a b = d + largestPower d b where d = a `div` b
```

However, the algorithm is not correct for composite `b`. For example, `largestPower 10 6` with this algorithm yields `1`, but in fact the correct answer is `4`. The problem is that this algorithm ignores multiples of `2` and `3` that are not multiples of `6`. How you fix the algorithm is a completely separate question, though.

Comment: Looks to me the correct answer is [4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10!%2F6%5E4).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're absolutely right. Fixed, thanks. That's what I get for doing my math hastily.